# Wordpress - rewrite or hide wp-json in url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, api, url-rewriting

I would like to hide `/wp-json/` from url since I don't want anyone to know that website is built on wordpress. I tried rewriting rules in `.htaccess`, but `/api` only redirects to `/wp-json` so this is not what I trully want.

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /wp-json/$1 [R,L]
```

These are not working at all:

```
RewriteRule ^api$ /wp-json [L]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /wp-json/$1 [L]
```

I also tried site_url hook event, but unfortunately it is not working at all:

```
add_filter('site_url', 'api_filter', 10, 3);
function api_filter($url, $path, $orig_scheme) {
    $old  = array('/(wp-json)/');
    $new  = array('api');
    return preg_replace($old, $new, $url, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the filter `rest_url_prefix` to do the rewrite:

```
add_filter( 'rest_url_prefix', function() {
    return 'api';
});
```

Remember to visit Settings->Permalinks to flush the permalinks after adding the above code to functions.php

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you alot!

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite the entire wp-json/wp/v2/ part? The rest_url_prefix filter only rewrites wp-json, correct? I'm currently building an app and would like the API url to be static because when it changes (eg wp-json/wp/v3) my app breaks and for every change an update of the app is necessary.